# node js return [Function] from controller file

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, mongoose

This is my first program in MEAN Stack..

server.js

```
var api = require('./controllers/list_controller.js');
app.get('/', function(req, res){
console.log(api.list);
})
```

list_controller.js

```
     var Thread = require('../models/list_model.js');
    module.exports.list = function(req, res) {
      Thread.find(function(err, dt) {
        if(!err){
            res.send({data:dt})
        }else{
          return res.status(500).send("Error");
        }


  });
}
```

list_models.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


module.exports = mongoose.model('posts', {
id:Number,
author:String,
title:String,
body:String
});
```

i am not getting output..it returns [Funtion]...not data

```
listening on 3000
Connected to mongodb
[Function]
```

Can anyone give solution..

Comment: You are logging the function, it prints `[Function]`. It is expected one. If you want to execute the function call with brackets api.list(req, res). You don't need to log, as the function is not returning anything. You will get `undefined` printed.

Comment: can you pls edit my code??